# RestFB: can't get page posts when page's URI has page's name

Tags: java, facebook, uri, restfb

I'm here again to ask for your help.
I'm building a simple application that gets all the comments from a page that I liked. It works very well, but during some tests I got HTTP Status 500 as exception.

The problem occours when the URI of the pase has the name of the page. Let me explain with two examples:

1. WORKING URI: https://www.facebook.com/pages/ULTRAS-NAPOLI/*101174668938*?fref=ts
2. **NOT** WORKING URI: https://www.facebook.com/*FASTWEB*?fref=ts

As you can see the difference between the two URIs is that 1. has page's ID, and 2. has page's name!

Here's my code:

```
   public LinkedList<String> writeOnePageComments(String id){
    LinkedList<String> s = new LinkedList<String>();

    Connection<Post> page = fb.fetchConnection(id.trim()+"/posts", Post.class,Parameter.with("limit",999));

    List<Post> pagePosts = page.getData();
    List<Comment> commentList;
    Comments comments;
    for(int i=0;i<pagePosts.size();i++){
        Post p=pagePosts.get(i);
        comments=p.getComments();
        if(comments!=null){
            commentList = comments.getData();
            if(!commentList.isEmpty())
                for(int k=0;k<commentList.size();k++){
                    String tmp = commentList.get(k).getMessage();
                    tmp = f.subEmoticons(tmp);
                    tmp = f.removeRepeatedVocals(tmp);
                    s.add(tmp);
                }
        }

    }
return s;
```

Any help? I'm going CRAZY! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
Connection<Post> page = fb.fetchConnection(id.trim()+"/posts", Post.class,Parameter.with("limit",999));
```

Should be changed to:

```
    Connection<Post> page = fb.fetchConnection(id.trim()+"/feed", Post.class,Parameter.with("limit",999));
```

According to Facebook Graph API Documentation, "feed" means: "The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by this page, or by others on this page. " , while "/posts" shows only the posts that were published by this page.